# Azure - Connecting multiple app service containers with custom domain and ssl

Tags: azure, ssl, devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am getting to the point of my project where I am ready to deploy it online with my custom domain via Azure once I make the upgrade from my Free Subscription.

So a little context, I have 1 web app service and 4 api services and each one is hosted in a separate app service such as:

`www.sitename.azurewebsites.net`

`www.sitename-api1.azurewebsites.net`

`www.sitename-api2.azurewebsites.net`

`www.sitename-api3.azurewebsites.net`

`www.sitename-api4.azurewebsites.net`

And the above web app communicates to all 4 api's and some api's may or may not talk to another. (Would have loved an application gateway so hopefully I'll be changing this architecture later down the road).

So as I get ready to associate my domain to the services, the web container seems pretty straight forward to me as it just becomes `www.sitename.com`, but I am a little confused about the api services. The way I am thinking about this is that each api service will be in it's own subdomain, such as:

`www.api1.sitename.net`

`www.api2.sitename.net`

`www.api3.sitename.net`

`www.api4.sitename.net`

where I believe I can register my SSL and domain to each app service somehow, but this leaves me with a few questions.

1. Do I host each api in a subdomain using the same domain as the web
   app, or is there a different way preferred like where I host them
   all on the same domain with different exposed ports per API and web
   listening 80/443, or maybe just use the IP address of the api app
   service and allow www.sitename.com as the origin for CORS?
2. I am assuming that since I am associating my SSL cert to the web
   service, I will need to do the following on the api services?
3. Would it be better (and still affordable) if I just had a VNET
   associated to the app services and the domain only registered with
   the web app?

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated on how I can establish communication between my app services with my custom domain and SSL as I am fairly new to this part of the stack, but excited about learning!

Answer (score 0):

As I known, on Azure cloud, there are two services can help to manage your APIs deployed on multiple app service containers: [API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/) and [Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/).

1. The Premium tier of API Management has the feature for multiple custom domain names, please see the offical document [Feature-based comparison of the Azure API Management tiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-features) as the figure below.

   [image]

   You can refer to the quick start tutorial of [`Create a new Azure API Management service instance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/get-started-create-service-instance) and other related documents to kown how to.
2. "Azure Application Gateway is a web traffic load balancer that enables you to manage traffic to your web applications." said in the introduce [What is Azure Application Gateway?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/overview). And as the figure of its architecture below, "With Application Gateway, you can make routing decisions based on additional attributes of an HTTP request, such as URI path or host headers. For example, you can route traffic based on the incoming URL. So if /images is in the incoming URL, you can route traffic to a specific set of servers (known as a pool) configured for images. If /video is in the URL, that traffic is routed to another pool that's optimized for videos."

   [image]

I recommended to use Azure Application Gateway which be a good choice to manage multiple app services and expose the unified urls of APIs.